# How to use Vue I18n internationalization with vue 3 SSR properly

Tags: vuejs3, server-side-rendering, vue-i18n

1. I make an instance of vue app with createSSRApp at my backend server start.
2. For every request I render HTML with renderToString(app, ctx). I pass the state inside the ctx object and the app instance remains the same for all the requests.
3. Then I need the internationalization. I create [Vue I18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/started.html) plugin with createI18n function and install it with app.use(i18n) method.

The problem is that the vue app instance is changed for every request (to backend). May be it won't be a problem due to single thread javascript nature, but it still seems ugly.

How can I avoid mutating the app instance on backend (SSR) when using [Vue I18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) library?

I didn't find anything that could help me with that problem in Vue I18n library web site. The obvious answer is to create an application for each request - not so good because of the impact on performance.